# Compare similar N-Dimensional vector in a database

Tags: ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom, near-neighbors

I want to compute Euclidian distance between similar vectors in a database (SQLite).
So each column in the database is a value from my vector.

The first problem appears, I have a large number of values that I first need to reduce to fit a reasonable number of rows (<50) since the original data have thousands of columns.
I have also thought of storing a blob, load it in memory and do my computations ?

Since I am trying to find the best matches (similarity mesure), I am currently filtering the database by applying a threshold for each value. Applying a filter for a small number of column is feasible, doing this for many columns is too time consuming.

Sqlite has a RTree module limited to 5 dimensions (11 columns). But it is not the filtering that I want.

What is the best compromise or technique/algorithm to sort and compare vectors using a database ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is a procedure to do near-neighbor searching in a high dimensional Euclidean space, or do dimensionality reduction prior to doing such a near neighbor search.

There are two approaches that are likely to help:

- Use a native near-neighbor search procedure that works in high dimensions. [Locality-sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) is a popular choice in this regard.
- Apply dimensionality reduction, and then use a technique that works for fewer dimensions. In this case, you should look at the [ANN near-neighbor library](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/), and also look into using the [Johnson-Lindenstrauss transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) for dimensionality reduction (or possibly even PCA to reduce dimensions).

(warning - self promotion alert: [I have a paper](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/papers/jlx/jlx.pdf) that describes different implementations of Johnson-Lindenstrauss and how they compare)